# Using Scala to represent two JSON fields of which only one can be null

Tags: json, scala, circe

Let's say my API returns a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "field1": "hey",
  "field2": null,
}
```

I have this **rule** that only one of these fields can be `null` at the same time. In this example, only `field2` is `null` so we're ok.

I can represent this in Scala with the following case class:

```scala
case class MyFields(
  field1: Option[String],
  field2: Option[String]
)
```

And by implementing some implicits and let `circe` do it's magic of converting the objects to JSON.

```
object MyFields {
  implicit lazy val encoder: Encoder[MyFields] = deriveEncoder[MyFields]
  implicit lazy val decoder: Decoder[MyFields] = deriveDecoder[MyFields]
```

Now, this strategy works. Kinda.

```
MyFields(Some("hey"), None)
MyFields(None, Some("hey"))
MyFields(Some("hey"), Some("hey"))
```

These all lead to JSONs that follow the **rule**. But it's also possible to do:

```
MyFields(None, None)
```

Which will lead to a JSON that breaks the **rule**.

So this strategy doesn't express the rule adequately. What's a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is based on [Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65355258/5082718) and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354583/using-scala-to-represent-two-json-fields-of-which-only-one-can-be-null/#comment115556137_65355258).)

[Cats `Ior` datatype](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/ior.html) could be used, as following:

```scala
import cats.data.Ior
import io.circe.parser._
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe._


case class Fields(fields: Ior[String, String])

implicit val encodeFields: Encoder[Fields] = (a: Fields) =>
  a.fields match {
    case Ior.Both(v1, v2) => Json.obj(
      ("field1", Json.fromString(v1)),
      ("field2", Json.fromString(v2))
    )
    case Ior.Left(v) => Json.obj(
      ("field1", Json.fromString(v)),
      ("field2", Json.Null)
      )
    case Ior.Right(v) => Json.obj(
      ("field1", Json.Null),
      ("field2", Json.fromString(v))
    )
  }

implicit val decodeFields: Decoder[Fields] = (c: HCursor) => {
  val f1 = c.downField("field1").as[Option[String]]
  val f2 = c.downField("field2").as[Option[String]]
  (f1, f2) match {
    case (Right(Some(v1)), Right(Some(v2))) => Right(Fields(Ior.Both(v1, v2)))
    case (Right(Some(v1)), Right(None)) => Right(Fields(Ior.Left(v1)))
    case (Right(None), Right(Some(v2))) => Right(Fields(Ior.Right(v2)))
    case (Left(failure), _) => Left(failure)
    case (_, Left(failure)) => Left(failure)
    case (Right(None), Right(None)) => Left(DecodingFailure("At least one of field1 or field2 must be non-null", Nil))
  }
}



println(Fields(Ior.Right("right")).asJson)
println(Fields(Ior.Left("left")).asJson)
println(Fields(Ior.both("right", "left")).asJson)


println(parse("""{"field1": null, "field2": "right"}""").flatMap(_.as[Fields]))
```

Answer (score 3):

represent your data as having a member `val field1or2 = Either[String, String]`. If the circe built-in `Codec.codecForEither` doesn't meet your exact requirements, you could write your codec manually. From what you describe (field1 and fiel2 both must be present in json, one as string, one as null), something like

```
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder, HCursor, Json, DecodingFailure}

case class Fields(fields: Either[String, String])

implicit val encodeFields: Encoder[Fields] = new Encoder[Fields] {
  final def apply(a: Fields): Json = Json.obj(a.fields match {
    case Left(str) => {
      "field1" -> Json.fromString(str)
      "field2" -> Json.Null
    }
    case Right(str) => {
      "field1" -> Json.Null
      "field2" -> Json.fromString(str)
    }
  })
}

implicit val decodeFields: Decoder[Fields] = new Decoder[Fields] {
  final def apply(c: HCursor): Decoder.Result[Fields] ={
    val f1 = c.downField("field1").as[Option[String]]
    val f2 = c.downField("field1").as[Option[String]]
    (f1, f2) match {
      case (Right(None), Right(Some(v2))) => Right(Fields(Right(v2)))
      case (Right(Some(v1)), Right(None)) => Right(Fields(Left(v1)))
      case (Left(failure), _) => Left(failure)
      case (_, Left(failure)) => Left(failure)
      case (Right(None), Right(None)) => Left(DecodingFailure("Either field1 or field2 must be non-null", Nil))
      case (Right(Some(_)), Right(Some(_))) => Left(DecodingFailure("field1 and field2 may not both be non-null", Nil))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not support the `MyFields(Some("hey"), Some("hey"))` example.

Comment: Ah I thought that option was supposed to be disallowed. You can use cats Ior (inclusive or) for the two element case. The code would get a bit simpler from that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of application-level verification of data, along with range-checking values and other consistency checks. As such, it doesn't really belong with the raw JSON parsing, but needs to be done in a separate validation step.

So I recommend having a set of classes that directly represent the JSON data, and then a separate set of application classes that use application data types rather than JSON data types.

When reading data, the JSON is read into the data classes to check that the underlying JSON is valid. Then those data classes are converted to application classes with appropriate validation and conversion (checking value ranges, changing strings to enumerations etc.)

This allows the data format to be changed (e.g. to XML or database) without affecting the application logic.

Comment: There is no need for an intermediate data structure, and in fact verifying this kind of constraint is exactly what the type system is for. http://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt The type system can only implement static constraints, but data validation usually has run-time constraints as well. And combining those run-time constraints with JSON parsing is breaking separation of concerns.

Comment: The type system can verify this constraint just fine, and Martijn has demonstrated how.

Comment: Oh, and validating these sorts of constraints during parsing has the significant advantage that circe will generate an error message that includes the precise location of the error. This can be extremely helpful when debugging.

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt The answer from martijn does not use the type system, it uses run-time tests. It is also incorrect, though that is not relevant to my answer.